# Calculating where two objects should meet when they have a set position at start

Tags: math

[image: Points A, B, C]

What I am trying to do is if I place two objects [A and B] at certain positions, how can I find where C should be? The velocities are not the same. Object A's velocity is 30 m/s, Object B's is 20 m/s.

In the picture, I have drawn that the velocities are the same. It should give you a general idea of what I am trying to do, though.

I have been messing around with this, but I do not even know where to start.

Thank you in advanced to all of you who reply.

Comment: Do you want to code this phenomena, or just the math behind it? If so, this should be posted is Math not in SO.

Comment: When you say, "meet", do you mean, where the two objects will collide (if they do collide), or just where their paths cross? If you're just looking for a crossing of paths, then velocity doesn't matter, only trajectory.

Comment: @SGM1 - I will put it into code later

Comment: @Kevin - Sorry, yes I do mean "collide"

Comment: Are the objects a and b actually squares? Or are they points? Because finding where two squares collide is much more involved than finding where two points collide.

Comment: @Kevin Yes, they are points

Comment: BTW, the points have a radius or they just literally points? If they are literally points, the collision will be nearly impossible to happen, because you'll need to have two precise start points to collide. I learned the math for this sort of problems in high school physics just FYI.

Comment: Are these points in 3d space? Or 2d space?

Comment: Again do the points have a radius? Without a radius it is a completely different problem (were talking about [parametrics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation#Parametric_form) purely then, correct me if I'm worng). And the direction & magnitude of each vector (of A and B) does matter if you want to know if they collide.

Comment: @Kevin Let's say they are in 2D space

Comment: @SGM1 No radius. It may be parametrics? I am not familiar with it. Yes, the direction & magnitude does matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, write two equations expressing the x position of each point at time t.

```
xpos_a(t) = original_xpos_a + xvelocity_a * t
xpos_b(t) = original_xpos_b + xvelocity_b * t
```

when the two points collide, their x positions will be equal. set xpos_a equal to xpos_b and solve for t.

```
original_xpos_a + xvelocity_a * t = original_xpos_b + xvelocity_b * t
xvelocity_a * t - xvelocity_b * t = original_xpos_b - original_xpos_a
t * (xvelocity_a - xvelocity_b) = original_xpos_b - original_xpos_a
t = (original_xpos_b - original_xpos_a) / (xvelocity_a - xvelocity_b)
```

there are three possible outcomes when you solve for t:

- both points have identical original position and velocity. `t = 0/0`; the collision might occur at any time.
- the points have identical velocty but different original positions. `t = [some nonzero number]/0`; the collision can never occur.
- the points have different velocity and different original positions. `t = some real number`. If the points do collide, the collision can only occur at this time.

Perform these same steps for Y (and Z, if the problem is three dimensional). Compare the t values from each dimension. There are four possible outcomes:

- any of the t values are "the collision can never occur". The collision will never occur.
- two or more of the t values are real numbers that are not equal. The collision will never occur.
- all t values are "the collision could occur at any time". The points are constantly colliding at every point on their trajectories.
- all of the t values that are real numbers are equal to one another. The collision will occur at that time. (if that time is negative, the collision occurs before you started your simulation; you may or may not want to count this as, "the collision will never occur")

If you end up in the final category, take the time of collision and plug it into the xpos_a, ypos_a, zpos_a functions to get the spatial coordinates of the collision.

Answer (score 1):

Given points A and B, and Vectors C ([velocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_of_motion#Kinematic_quantities) of A) and D (velocity of B).

```
A = (x1, y1) >start point of A
B = (x2, y2) >start point of B
C = (q1, w1) >constant velocity of A
D = (q2, w2) >constant velocity of B
```

NOTE: x1, y1, x2, y2, q1, q2, w1, w2 are all constants

EDIT: Follow works given that A & C and b& D aren't co-linear (just find time of collision if they do collide as Kevin points out)

Do linearization(can't find a good reference) of them:

```
EQ1 => (x-x1)(w1/q1)=(y-y1) >> (x-x1)(w1/q1) + y1 = y <br>
EQ2 => (x-x2)(w2/q2)=(y-y2) >> (x-x2)(w2/q2) + y2 = y <br>

EQ1 => (w1/q1) * x + y1 - x1(w1/q1) = y
         m1    * x +(     b1      ) = y

EQ2 => (w2/q2) * x + y2 - x2(w2/q2) = y
         m2    * x +(     b2      ) = y
```

Solve EQ1 and EQ2 for `x` and `y`

```
x = (b2 - b1)/(m1 - m2)
y = m1 * x + b1    OR    m2 * x + b2
```

The `(x,y)` referred to later ^

Solve for `t1` or `t2`

```
t1 = (x-x1) / q1
t2 = (x-x2) / q2
```

Check if t1 and t2 is true for the `y`s

```
t1 ?= (y-y1) / w1
t2 ?= (y-y2) / w2
```

If they are the same, then yes they collide, at `(x,y)`

NOTE: Due to round off error unless everything is perfectly calcualted before hand, most likely nothing will collide